# display:none on all but first child element

Tags: css

```
<p><span>*</span>Here lies a note.</p>
```

Using CSS, how can I hide (that is, `display:none`) the text “Here lies a note.” and show just the “*”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can't select text nodes with CSS, one option is to set the `font-size` of the parent element to `0`, which will effectively hide all the text. Then you can reset the text for the desired element.

```css
.target {
  font-size: 0;
}
.target > :first-child {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p class="target">
  <span>First node</span>
  Second node
  More text nodes...
</p>
```

---

Alternatively, you could also utilize the [`visibility` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) as well (since you can set a child element to `visibility: visible` even when the parent element is set to `visibility: hidden`:

```css
.target {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.target > :first-child {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p class="target">
  <span>First node</span>
  Second node
  More text nodes...
</p>
```

---

As a side note, if you want an alternative, you could wrap the text nodes with `<span>` elements using JavaScript, and then set the `display` of all the children element that aren't the first child to `none` using the selector:

```
.target > :not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is a snippet demonstrating this:

```js
var target = document.querySelector('.target');
Array.from(target.childNodes).forEach(function (node, index) {
  if (node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue.trim()) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = node.nodeValue;
    target.replaceChild(span, node);
  }
});
```

```css
.target > :not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="target">
  <span>First node</span>
  Second node
  More text nodes...
</p>
```

---

If you're using jQuery, it would be even shorter:

```js
$('.target').contents()
  .filter(function () {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
  }).wrap('<span />');
```

```css
.target > :not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="target">
  <span>First node</span>
  Second node
  More text nodes...
</p>
```

Comment: It would here, but visibility won’t always work, since space is still taken up. 

Is `font-size:0` OK to do? I thought I’d read that some browsers misbehave with it.

Comment: @JPM - Yeah, it will still take up space when using `visibility: hidden`, so I would personally go with the `font-size` option since it will work consistently. It all depends on what you're trying to achieve I guess.

Comment: spotted elsewhere: “Some browsers allow the user to set a minimum font size, that can not be under-run by the stylesheet of any website, and there are even browsers that have such a minimum value set by default (so the user does not have to actively chose it) … so your labels might show up after all.”

Comment: @JPM- Which browsers?

Comment: I don’t know. In Chrome, I see a minimum font size under Advanced Settings > Web content > Customize fonts, but it does not seem to stop me from setting font-size = 0 in jsfiddle.

Comment: I could even just `.detach()` them. The Javascript approaches do have the downside that the page flickers when the script runs. The text appears then disappears. I’d prefer the font-size=0 approach if I knew it worked everywhere.

Comment: On Windows, the latest Firefox, Edge, Chrome, and Opera all honored font-size=0, even when a minimum font size was chosen. They behaved in various ways as font-size was lowered but all made the text vanish at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `visibility` to hide parent and show child element.

```css
p {
  visibility: hidden;
}
p > :first-child {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p><span>*</span>Here lies a note.</p>
```

Comment: Initially downvoted this thinking it wouldn't work. Pleasantly surprised. Neat. How well supported is `visibility`? (Looks like I'm not the only one who mistakenly downvoted)

Comment: You can see browser compatibility at end of  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility